# Присвоить новому массиву значения Одного поля из уже существующего

Tags: javascript

у меня есть массив[image: Массив]

Мне нужно присвоить новому массиву только поля field, которые также будут string

Answer (score 3):

```js
let array = [
    { field: '123' },
    { field: '1234' },
    { field: '1235' },
    { field: '1236' },
    { field: '1237' },
], newArray = array.map(e => e.field);

console.log(newArray);
```